# How to fix the error 'I can't write on file `document.pdf'?

Tags: output

I attach the document code. I don't understand what's wrong. Before that, everything worked, but after updating the MiKTeX packages, this error appeared. I work in the Texstudio program.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{ncc}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, headsep=0.7cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} % Поддержка русских букв
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Кодировка utf8
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} % Языки: русский, английский
\usepackage{fontspec} % Настройка для подключения
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} % шрифта Times New Roman
\usepackage{indentfirst} % Красная строка
\usepackage{xcolor} % Пакет для работы с цветами
\usepackage{hyperref} % Гиперссылки
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts,amscd}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{plain} % Номера страниц ставятся снизу и по центру
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep, labelsep=0.2cm, leftmargin=0cm} % Отступы номеров
% Настройка некоторых параметров ссылок
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true, % Ссылки цветные? - Да
    linkcolor = {blue!50!black}, % Цвет внутренних ссылок
    citecolor = {red!75!black}, % Цвет ссылок на библиографию
    urlcolor = red, % Цвет ссылок на внешние (Интернет) ресурсы
}

\DeclareSymbolFont{lsymb}{U}{euex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{lsymb}{"52}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointop}{\mathop}{lsymb}{"48}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\smallint}{\mathop}{lsymb}{"52}

\begin{document}
    Текст
\end{document}
```

Comment: The official language of this site is English, you'll be much more likely to get an answer if you translate your question to English, even if you just use google translate, don't worry if the translation isn't perfect, someone will probably fix it. If google translate is correct then this MWE stopped compiling after updating MikTeX, is this correct?

Comment: When I get this error, it has always meant that I have the PDF output open with a separate PDF viewer program (e.g. Adobe), which locks write access to the file.  If I close that window, the PDF can again be overwritten by MikTeX.

Comment: Steven B. Segletes,
I don't have a PDF viewer from Adobe.

Comment: @Pavel other programs may lock the file or you may not have write access to the current directory, essentially this is not a tex error but an operating system file access error stopping you write the file at this location

Comment: Interestingly, it turns out that no matter which document and in which directory you create it, the file is still not written. For example, what program can block a file?

Comment: I could imagine Dropbox and Nextcloud to block a file, but you would have to have a really bad internet connection.

Comment: I suppose restarting the computer can fix the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the error was Avast antivirus. He perceived the LuaLaTeX compiler as malicious. When the process started lualatex.exe, the antivirus issued a message in which I clicked the "Allow application" button, and the error disappeared.